# Jmeter getting out of memory exception. What should I change the heap size to?

Tags: jmeter, out-of-memory

I'm trying to do some load testing with jmeter with about 10000 to 15000 load. when i try to run the script in command-line I'm getting the out of memory exception. I have read that you can increase the JVM memory in the JMeter batch file and modify HEAP size in the JMeter batch file up to 80% of total memory.

So what i'm assuming is there's two files to edit. Can someone confirm me what file should be edited exactly please. I'm running jmeter on a 12GB RAM machine and current have not setup any method for distributed testing. So what is the proper way to allocate more memory to jmeter?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html) exception has many faces and only one of them is connected with the lack of heap space. If you believe that's your case: you don't need to edit any file in order to change the heap size, it's sufficient to set `HEAP` [environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) variable

Windows:

```
set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx10g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m && jmeter.bat
```

Unix and derivatives:

```
export HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx10g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m && ./jmeter.sh
```

If you want to make the change permanent - find the following lines and amend them accordingly:

- Windows: [line 151 of `jmeter.bat`](https://set%20HEAP=-Xms1g%20-Xmx1g%20-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m) file
- Unix and derivatives: [line 166 of `jmeter` file](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/jmeter#L166)

the line numbers are provided for [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)

However be informed that larger your heap size - more time it will be required for the [garbage collection](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) and most probably JMeter won't be sending any requests during that period.